# \bibentry and \nobibliography* produces broken link and no bibliography

Tags: bibentry

I am using the `bibentry` package to insert bibliography entries into my document. In my particular case, I will also need a regular bibliography entry. From what I've understood, to accomplish this, I need to use `\nobibliography*` in conjunction with `\bibliography`.

This code works fine:

```
    \documentclass{report}
    \usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
    \usepackage{bibentry}
    \nobibliography*
    \begin{document}
    \chapter{Introduction}
    text~\citet{haertel_return_2008}

    more text

    \bibentry{haertel_return_2008}

    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
    \bibliography{al}
    \end{document}
```

With the following sample `.bib` file:

```
    @inproceedings{haertel_return_2008,
        Author = {Author, First},
        Booktitle = {Booktitle},
        Title = {Title},
        Year = {2008}
    }
```

However, when I switch the document class to the [one I am required to use](https://code.google.com/p/latex-byu-thesis/downloads/detail?name=latex-byu-thesis-1.4.tar.gz&can=2&q=), it no longer works. The problem can also be seen using `article` or `report` classes in a slightly different context, namely, when using `\nobibliography{al}` (and no corresponding `\bibliography` command).

Here is a link to some full working example that can be compiled and viewed entirely online using sharelatex; I've made it editable in case it is helpful:

- [Using the required class](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/51df4590cad12b446f2a0050)
- Alternative using report class found at www.sharelatex.com/project/51e0437ecad12b446f54bb5a

Comment: The package `bibentry` is from 1999 and it seems it doesn't work well with newer version of `natbib`. However I think `biblatex` would be a good choice.

Comment: @Marco Daniel. Thanks for the heads up. For various reasons, I probably can't switch to biblatex. If this is indeed a conflict between bibentry and natbib, I guess I'll have to do things manually. However, I have some hope of finding a solution since it does work in many cases.

Comment: The class here is defective: even with no packages loaded and no text at all I get `(\end occurred inside a group at level 1)`. That's a bad sign! However, I don't have any errors if I compile the demo with my local system, which is fully up to date. Which `natbib` do you have?

Comment: With no feedback on my earlier comment, I'm afraid this looks 'unclear' (as it's not really reproducible).