# Problem with bibliography entries (bibentry, \nobibliography) in TeXstudio

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, texstudio, bibentry

I have a problem with getting bibliographies in the text using `bibentry` package. I followed a suggestion in the comments [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123678/bibentry-and-nobibliography-produces-broken-link-and-no-bibliography), but it didn't work either. In the Options->Config->Completion the `natbib.cwl` is checked.

So what's happening essentially is I get black space instead of bibliography in the text. In the document preamble I have

```
\usepackage{bibentry}
\nobibliography{source.bib}
```

So the first problem is that `\nobibliography{source.bib}` is marked red as unrecognized command.
In the text of course I use `\bibentry{relevant entry}`, which is also marked as unrecognized command.

So any suggestions are very welcome.

EDIT: I used the code snippet from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33008/what-is-the-most-convenient-way-to-create-annotated-bibliographies-e-g-in-a-li):

```
\documentclass{article}

% This is the sample bib file
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Saussure1995,
    Author = {Ferdinand de Saussure},
    Origyear = {1916},
    Publisher = {Payot},
    Title = {Cours de Linguistique G{\'e}n{\'e}rale},
    Year = {1995}}

\end{filecontents}


\usepackage{natbib,bibentry}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\begin{document}
\nobibliography{\jobname}
This is a complete citation in the middle of the text: 

\bibentry{Saussure1995}

\end{document}
```

And get a blank page, no errors reported. If I use biblatex instead (from the same answer), I just get the reference number, in this case `Saussure1995`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) To me your problem does not get quite clear. Do you get error messages and unexpected output after compilation or is only TexStudio marking some commands in red to tell that they were not recognized? Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @BenediktBauer: please see the edit

Comment: Did you compile with `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex`?

Comment: pdflatex+bibtex

Comment: Compiling your code with chain suggested by Benedikt Bauer works fine for me.

Comment: @AndrewSwann thanks, finally sorted it out! It turned out I didn't check thoroughly the build and compile settings

Comment: @AndrewSwann: also, I had to rename \nobibliography{source.bib} to \nobibliography{source}. I don't know why, but it used to work with the .bib extension before.

Comment: Good that you sorted this out.  We should probably close this question now.